# Calculate the sum $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+w_k)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let $w_k=\exp\left(\frac {2\pi ki}n\right)$. I have already proven that

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}w_k^p=n\qquad n\mid p$$

If not, then

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} w_k^p=0$$

How can I prove that

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+w_k)^n=2n$$

My attempt so far has been to expand the inner binomial using the binomial theorem.

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+w_k)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\binom np w_k^p$$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\binom np w_k^p=\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\binom np\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} w_k^p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Change the order of the summation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+w_k)^n
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{p=0}^n\binom np w_k^p
=\sum_{p=0}^n \binom np \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w_k^p
$$
and note that inner sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}w_k^p$ is zero except for $p=0$ and $p=n$, where it is equal to $n$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+w_k)^n = \binom n0 n + \binom nn n = 2n \, .
$$